# Two Tables in diffrent databases foregn key relationship

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Suppose we Have `DataBase 1` which contains `Table 1`, and `DataBase 2` which contain `Table 2` containing a column `table_id`.

Is it possible to create a foreign key on DataBase2.Table2.`table_id` related to DataBase1.Table1.`id`

Comment: Do you mean a foreign key? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh yes i mean foreign key

Answer (score 1):

No. Even if db link is implemented, DDL commands (structural changes) are not allowed over multiple databases. [Oracle SQL]